# how to bring up the menu at the bottom left

Tags: shortcut

hello everyone I have a little problem, how do I bring up the menu in the circle? when I select another object the menu becomes non-existent

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Adjust Last Operation* panel can be re-opened by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> or by using the menu *Edit > Adjust Last Operation*.

[image: Edit menu]

Comment: yeah its work thank dude for help me!!