# Making Multiple Loop Cuts

Tags: loop

I have a cylinder that I want to make many loop cuts in so I can reshape it. (Loops cuts are around the perimeter, i.e. rings)

I'm using Blender 2.8.

Every tutorial tells me I can add a loop cut, press Ctrl-R or PgUp/PgDn and this will allow me to **multiply** the number of cuts.

This does not work for me. When I press Ctrl-R the cursor changes to two short black arrows - when I slide the wheel, the **one ring slides up and down the length** of the cylinder. (PgUp/PgDn does nothing at all.) Haven't found any combination of keys that will allow me to multiply the loops.

(I guess, failing anything else, I can always add additional cuts manually.)

Comment: go to edit preferences keymap and have a look on what is crtl r assigned to?

Comment: Don't "click" after pressing Ctrl+R, then try scrolling the mouse wheel. The two black arrows don't appear until you "set" the loop by clicking the mouse - up until this point, mousewheel scrolling or pgup/pgdn should work fine to increase the number of "rings".

Comment: You just press Ctrl+R only and the when the first loop appears just scroll down or up as per your choice of increasing or decreasing loops.

Answer (score 3):

It never worked like this in Blender 2.8+ (using PGUp/PgDn to adjust loops).
But you can use the pop-up menu, it gives you better control.

[image]

Comment: Popup menu doesn't appear.

Comment: Hello :). This could help: [How to bring up the menu at the bottom left](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/159565/78972)